# preselected other option in select

Tags: php, html

I have this part code

```
<select id="category" name="category" class="col-md-5">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
      <option><?= $category['name'] ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </select>
```

I have categories Number1, Number2, Number3

When I go on page I have automatically preselected
Number 1. I want to have preselected other option  for Examle
Number 2.  How I Can make this?

Comment: pay more attention your question content, please following as url tutors https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help / https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `selected` attribute to the option when you get the category name you want.

```
<option<?= ($category['name'] == "Number2" ? " selected" : "") . ">" . $category['name'] ?></option>
```